# Spring vs. Zeus performance issue: Spring not running tests much faster after 1st run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, zeus, rake-test

So I'm trying to improve my test execution time, and have been following some of the excellent advice out there (most notably, [Railscasts 412](http://railscasts.com/episodes/412-fast-rails-commands)).

Zeus seems to be working fine (other than the weirdness that requires you to type `zeus test test` in order to run the Minitest suite.)

Here's the timed output from zeus:

Baseline (rake test):

```
$ time rake test
Run options: --seed 62848

# Running tests:

........

Finished tests in 0.117071s, 68.3346 tests/s, 68.3346 assertions/s.

8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m5.771s
user    0m4.477s
sys     0m0.872s
```

And with Zeus:

```
$ time zeus test test
Run options: --seed 10325

# Running tests:

........

Finished tests in 0.126365s, 63.3087 tests/s, 63.3087 assertions/s.

8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m0.765s
user    0m0.209s
sys     0m0.030s
```

Good.  5.7s down to 0.7s.

Now, with spring, I'm just not seeing the improvement after the first run.  I'm running Spring gem 1.1.0beta4, installing as-described (adding to Gemfile, then running `bundle exec spring binstub --all`).

And here's what I've got:

Baseline, 1st execution (rake test):

```
time bin/rake test
Run options: --seed 49915

# Running tests:

........

Finished tests in 0.108359s, 73.8287 tests/s, 73.8287 assertions/s.

8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m6.265s
user    0m0.072s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Confirm that spring is running:

```
$ spring status
Spring is running:

 2990 spring server | gdc4 | started 43 secs ago  
 2991 spring app    | gdc4 | started 43 secs ago | test mode
```

And run the tests again...

```
$ time bin/rake test
Run options: --seed 27416

# Running tests:

........

Finished tests in 0.132677s, 60.2968 tests/s, 60.2968 assertions/s.

8 tests, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

real    0m3.885s
user    0m0.069s
sys     0m0.014s
```

So a bit of a speedup, but still almost 4 seconds to execute.  Meanwhile, btw, the rails console DOES load up a ton faster w/ Spring....< 1 second.

So, my question is:  Why is Zeus able to get the order-of-magnitude speedup on tests (5.7s -> 0.7s) but Spring is not?

Running Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0 btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run

> rake test

you need to run

> spring rake test

Example:

time rake -T

10.737s

time rake -T

10.811s           # no improvement, as you noted

time spring rake -T

18.468s

time spring rake -T

1.140s            # huge improvement

Answer (score 0):

I've only played with spring a little bit and haven't compared times against zeus (which I prefer) but my guess is you're still seeing the slow [ruby] startup time of spring itself. Zeus doesn't have any of that since it's written in Go.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same difference here. 
Running the rails server for instance:
 with zeus < 1s
 with spring ~ 4s

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `zeus test` doesn't run `db:reset`.

On one of my applications, Spring runs tests in 5-6s, whereas Zeus runs them in about 0.5s, and it's definitely due to Spring reloading the database each time.